# Message passing(or not) to UIScrollView

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiscrollview, message-queue

I have the following problem.

On a UIScrollView are laid out several components : UIPickerView(s), UIButton(s), UILabel(s), different kinds of customized subclasses of UIView …etc...

How can I decide that for some components the finger motions should be handled by the component itself and for some others it should be handled by the UIScrollView underneath?

Thanks for any tip of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this question and put it here in case someone has the same problem. The overwriting of hitTest in the customized UIView did the trick, here is the code :

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{return nil;}
```